Replace the tab character with a space in all lists in a Word document
I need to replace the tab symbol in all lists so that when I copy it to the clipboard and paste it in another program, the tab symbol does not appear.
Example of inserting into another program:
That's not right:
1.[tab]Trade and other receivables do not include taxes and prepayments.
•[tab]Trade and other payables do not include taxes, employee benefits provision and contract liabilities.
That's right:

Trade and other receivables do not include taxes and prepayments.

• Trade and other payables do not include taxes, employee benefits provision and contract liabilities.

I know there is such a function
But I need to replace in the entire document at once.
Thanks for the help
